# What is the music that plays when Shirley is testing out the headphones?

Tags: music, code-geass

There's this song in Code Geass I really like. It plays when Lelouch partially erases Shirley's memories in R1 and when Shirley is testing out the headphones in maybe episode 3 in R2 (at around the 18 minutes mark). Can someone please tell me its name?

Comment: The song can be heard at around 18 minutes in R2EP3, and also in R1EP14.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/CodeGeass/comments/4ndd6h/whats_the_song/) the song is [Masquerade](https://soundcloud.com/mikazuki-anisa/code-geass-masquerade-insert)

The vocals, lyrics and composition seem to be all done by [Kuroishi Hitomi](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/people.php?id=2635)

It's a great song, it's a shame they seem to have all been taken down off of youtube. If you want a physical copy, Masquerade is the 13th track on [this album](http://www.cdjapan.co.jp/product/VICL-62187).